# Why Could Not Deduce Template Argument When Function Returns a Struct Template

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I'm trying to overload a CreateBST function which accepsts an iterable container of elements and its size. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename ElementType>
struct BTreeNode
{
    ElementType value;
    BTreeNode<ElementType>* left;
    BTreeNode<ElementType>* right;
};

template <typename ContainerType, typename ElementType>
BTreeNode<ElementType>* CreateBST(const ContainerType& elements, const size_t num_elements);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> elems{ 67, 34, 82, 12, 45, 78 };
    
    BTreeNode<int>* btree = CreateBST(elems, elems.size());
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
error C2672: 'CreateBST': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: 'BTreeNode<ElementType> *CreateBST(const ContainerType &,const size_t)': could not deduce template argument for 'ElementType'
```

Can someone explain me why I am getting this error? Also, how am I supposed to declare a function to take an template template parameter like std::vector and it's element type?

Comment: Because only function parameters can be deduced. Pretend that you're a C++ compiler. You have this line of code: `CreateBST(elems, elems.size());`. You know what `elems` is. Now, tell me, what is the actual, concrete type that you deduced for `ElementType`, and how exactly were you able to deduce it? How do you expect your C++ compiler to know what `ElementType` is, here?

Comment: please focus on one question per question. For your individual questions there are already answers

Comment: `BTreeNode<int>* btree = CreateBST<std::vector<int>, int>(elems, elems.size());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain me why I am getting this error?

Template parameters can only be deduced from the arguments at the call site. While that information, i.e. `ElementType` is actually present in the type of the first argument, your template doesn't know how to extract that type.

---

> how am I supposed to declare a function to take an template template parameter like std::vector and it's element type?

Like this:

```
template <template <typename...> class ContainerType, 
          typename ElementType>
BTreeNode<ElementType>* CreateBST(const ContainerType<ElementType>& elements, 
                                  const size_t num_elements);
```

Note that the first template parameter is a template template parameter. This allows you to pass in a `vector<int>`, and deduce the `int` part of the type.

Comment: Or `template <class ContainerType>
BTreeNode<typename ContainerType::value_type>* CreateBST(const ContainerType& elements, const size_t num_elements);` ... relying on `value_type` being typedef'd.

Comment: I get the following linker errors:  
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct BTreeNode<int> * __cdecl CreateBST<class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >,int>(class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &,unsigned int)" (??$CreateBST@V?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@H@@YAPAU?$BTreeNode@H@@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@I@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: Well, you haven't defined the function anywhere, there's only a declaration.